# Convert html to pdf with ajax and mpdf

Tags: javascript, php, mpdf

I have list of html stored in database, I want to retrieve the data and convert it to pdf and after converting download it with via ajax request.

I tried hands on it but when the pdf get download the downloaded file is empty.
Please what do i need to do?
Thank you.

JS Code

```
SMSLiTe('click','.export-to-pdf',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  ///export note to pdf via ajax
  if (typeof notes[0].note.nid !== typeof undefined && notes.length) {
  var nid = notes[0].note.nid;
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('export_to_pdf',true);
  fd.append('note_id',nid);
  request.open(bigPipe.formMethod.a, 'pdf/pdf');
  request.send(fd);
  request.onload = function(e){
    if (request.readyState == request.DONE && request.status ==200) {
        //code here ....download
        var data = request.responseText,
        blob = new Blob([data]),
        a = document.createElement('a'), d = new Date();
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = d.getTime()+'.pdf'; a.click();

    }
  }
  }else{
  sustainScroll(bigPipe.c_w,bigPipe.class.fixed);
  var msg = 'Sorry! something gone wrong, please refresh this page and try again.',title = 'Export Failed';
  $(bigPipe.document).append(flexibleDialog({content:templateHTML.flexDialog(msg,title,'_2d0',null,'Close',null,0),isClass:'export_to_pdf_failed _2d0',heigt:140,width:600}));jkg();  
  }
});
```

PHP Code

```
if (isset($_POST['note_id'],$_POST['export_to_pdf'])) {
$nid = (int)$_POST['note_id'];
$sql = "SELECT content  FROM $notes_table WHERE note_id='{$nid}' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$content = $row['content'];
//create PDF file
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
$mpdf->Output(time().'.pdf','D');exit;
}
}
```

Comment: You should return path of pdf, which is created  by mpdf.

Comment: I am not storing file to server.

Comment: I am attaching the pdf created by mpdf to the bworser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting the response data returning from MPDF I realized the output data was a blob and since the data was already blob data. I had a clue of changing the responseType of **XMLHttpRequest.responseType** to **blob**

and it worked for now.

modified JS:

```
SMSLiTe('click','.export-to-pdf',function(event){
event.preventDefault();

//set request method
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {  // code for IE6, IE5
var request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}


  ///export note to pdf via ajax
  if (typeof notes[0].note.nid !== typeof undefined && notes.length) {
  var nid = notes[0].note.nid;
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('export_to_pdf',true);
  fd.append('note_id',nid);
  request.open(bigPipe.formMethod.a, 'pdf/pdf');
  request.send(fd);

  request.responseType = 'blob';//change reponseType before onload

  request.onload = function(e){
    if (request.readyState == request.DONE && request.status ==200) {
        //code here ....download
        var data = request.response,
        blob = new Blob([data],{type: 'application/pdf'}),
        a = document.createElement('a'), d = new Date();
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = d.getTime()+'.pdf'; a.click();
        //console.log(data);
    }
  }
  }else{
  sustainScroll(bigPipe.c_w,bigPipe.class.fixed);
  var msg = 'Sorry! something gone wrong, please refresh this page and try again.',title = 'Export Failed';
  $(bigPipe.document).append(flexibleDialog({content:templateHTML.flexDialog(msg,title,'_2d0',null,'Close',null,0),isClass:'export_to_pdf_failed _2d0',heigt:140,width:600}));jkg();  
  }
});
```

PHP Code:
We have to output MPDF as string since we're not appending MPDF to browser;

```
//create PDF file
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
$output  = $mpdf->Output(time().'.pdf','S');//output as string
echo($output); //final result to JS as blob data
```